# Convert py file with multiple imports and data files (.png, .jpg) to exe

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze

Please how to i convert my py file to exe.

My py file is a gui program developed with tkinter and contains the following.

  imports multiple modules (both built-in, third party, and the ones i created)

  data files (images, jpeg, png)

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['weldFunctions.py'],
         pathex=['c:\\users\Python-Files\\Gui\\FilletWeld'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='weldFunctions',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=False )
```

Comment: `pyinstaller` is the currently most popular tool for this, so can you show us what you have tried with that tool?

Comment: Thanks AKX for your response. Please below. this is done with spec file.

Comment: @Mexes4453 py2exe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395538/cant-get-py2exe-to-work/42483641#42483641

Comment: ... What's _your_ problem with py2exe and a spec file? As far as I can see that's not your question or answer?

Comment: @AKX, after i convert to exe my program does not run. it show error. i think i have not done something right